# Script to flatten nested directories

Tags: bash, scripting

I found this script by Bruno that flattens a directory.  Can someone tell me how to modify it to run it as loop so it would work on all directories within a specified (higher level) directory?
Thank you in advance ;)

```
# This scripts flattens the file directory
# Run this script with a folder as parameter:
# $ path/to/script path/to/folder

#!/bin/bash

rmEmptyDirs(){
    local DIR="$1"
    for dir in "$DIR"/*/
    do
        [ -d "${dir}" ] || continue # if not a directory, skip
        dir=${dir%*/}
        if [ "$(ls -A "$dir")" ]; then
            rmEmptyDirs "$dir"
        else
            rmdir "$dir"
        fi
    done }

flattenDir(){
    local DIR="$1"
    find "$DIR" -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -i '{}' "$DIR" ';' }

flattenDir "$1" rmEmptyDirs "$1" echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just one line will move all files (in child subdirs) to pwd.

```
$ find  . -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv {} .. \;
```

This will move all regular files including dot-files (start with a dot) but not links.

Then, remove empty dirs:

```
$ find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Whatever is left out contains links (or other types of files) not moved.

If you want an script, use:

```
#!/bin/bash

fullpath=${1:-.}

( cd "$fullpath";
  find  . -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv {} .. \;
  find . -type d -empty -delete
)
```

Call the script as: `script /the/path/you.want`

Comment: What if you aren't in the current directory? If you want to use it in a script and use a full path?

Comment: @Freedo Just cd to the path you want and execute the command as shown. Added an script.

Comment: This script doesn't move files to the current directory, it moves scripts to the directory one up from the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

One way to perform a certain operation all directories found within a given directory, is

```
setopt -s nullglob
for e in SPECIFIED_DIRECTORY/*
do
  setopt -u nullglob
  [[ -d $e ]] && YOUR_SCRIPT "$e"
done
```

Note that this will skip directories where the name starts with a dot. This is usually what we want, but if you want to include those directories as well, you can adapt my solution to this case too: See the `dotglob` option in the man page, and don't forget to exclude the special directories `.` and `..`.

Another possibilitiy is to use something like

```
find SPECIFIED_DIRECTORY -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec YOUR_SCRIPT {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you user1934428.  How would I change your script to run YOUR script in CURRENT directory instead SPECIFIED_DIRECTORY?

Comment: The current directory (I guess you mean: *working directory*) can be denoted by a single period (`.`) or by using the shell variable PWD (`$PWD`).